# Java OutOfMemoryError on sbt assembly

Tags: java, scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I tried to launch `sbt assembly` with some library dependencies.
When I tried to add

```
"edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.5.1",
"edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.5.1" classifier "models",
```

It closes with an error :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
at sbtassembly.Assembly$.sha1content(Assembly.scala:294)
at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$24.apply(Assembly.scala:206)
at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$24.apply(Assembly.scala:202)
...
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

When I add `provided` property to these librairies, it works well.

I added the options on the `build.sbt` like mentioned on the [README file of SBT assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) but nothing changed.

```
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(cacheUnzip = false)
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(cacheOutput = false)
javaOptions in assembly += "-Xmx2g"
```

Run on

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.1")
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Increase heap size of your sbt process as below

set this property in your .bashrc file as a permanent fix. Edit the memeory limit as per your need and resources

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2G -Xss2M  -Duser.timezone=GMT"
```

After edit refresh your console with,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Added `export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2048M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xss4M -Duser.timezone=GMT+1"` but same error.
Forgot to mention I use Java 8 so MaxPermSize is not useful.